# Exit Intent in Mobile using javascrpt or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried modifying the plugin to show a modal popup when a website visitor leaves the page using haschange, but it still doesn't work. How to get it to work? I need help fixing it

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var exit_intent_popup_hash = 'b'
    window.location.hash = exit_intent_popup_hash
    window.history.back()

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.history.forward()
        $('.fel-modal-parent-wrapper').each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);
            var tmp_id = $this.attr('id');
            var popup_id = tmp_id.replace('-overlay', '');
            var trigger_on = $this.data('trigger-on');
            var exit_intent = $this.data('exit-intent');

            if ('automatic' == trigger_on) {
                if ('yes' == exit_intent && FelModalPopup_canShow(popup_id)) {
                
                    $(window).hashchange(function() {
                        if (window.location.hash !== `#${exit_intent_popup_hash}`) {
                            FelModalPopup_show(popup_id);
                            window.history.forward()
                        }
                    }, false);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I found some examples I found by using hashchange.Please help me modify it.
This for reference
'''
exit_intent_popup_starter(function() {
    var exit_intent_popup_hash = 'b'
    window.location.hash = exit_intent_popup_hash
    window.history.back()
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.history.forward()
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
            if (window.location.hash !== `#${exit_intent_popup_hash}`) {
                exit_intent_show_modal()
                window.history.forward()
            }
        }, false)
    }, 500)
})
'''

Comment: please edit and correct the word 'javascript' in question title so that it helps others too!